# HolographicAppRemoting.dll not found, while building the app for Hololens Emulator

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, hololens, hololens-emulator

I am following this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/holograms-101e) to build a sample app for Hololens (1st Gen). In Chapter 1 ("Holo" World) of the tutorial, while building the app for Hololens Emulator, I received the following error after successful compilation,

```
2>------ Build started: Project: Origami, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
2>C:\...\HolographicAcademy-Holograms-101\Origami\App\Origami\Unity Data.vcxitems(197,9): error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "C:\...\HolographicAcademy-Holograms-101\Origami\App\Origami\Plugins\x86\HolographicAppRemoting.dll" because it was not found.
2>Done building project "Origami.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I also imported the MRTK package from [here](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/releases) and configured it in the scene, but still I am not able to build the app.

Here are my settings for Unity 2019.2.0f1 and Visual Studio 2019,

[image: Unity Build Settings]

[image: Visual Studio Settings]

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue but failed. Depending on your error message, it seems to be related to Holographic Remoting. Have you tried to turn off this feature in unity?

Comment: I have the same issue, and I disable the feature, but still throws the same error. Any idea on how to resolve the issue?
@Hernando also could you share your unity project or the steps that you follow?. Also you are using the last version of unity?

Comment: My development environment is similar to Saurabh P Bhandari. I noticed that MR Basics Tutorial was a bit outdated. If you are using MRTKv2,  it is recommended to follow this tutorial(https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/GettingStartedWithTheMRTK.html) to initialize the project.

Answer (score 2):

Just disable WSA Holographic Rendering Supported in the XR settings before making a build. Remember to re-enable it for use with the Holographic Remoting app.

Answer (score 0):

I was hitting this on Unity 2019.2.0f1 as well with MRTK v2.0.0.
I was able to work around it by opening UnityData.vcxitems and manually removing any mentions of HolographicAppRemoting.dll, UnityRemotingWMR.dll and PerceptionDevice.dll and then it works.

Annoying thing is that everytime you build in Unity, those entries get put back in the .vcxitems again :( still havent figured out a way to fix that though. It seems to be related to MRTK or some packages I had to add to get MRTK to work properly since some of hte other projects I have sans MRTK do not face this issue.

Edit: I think I figured it out...

In order to enable Holographic Remoting through Unity, the editor force you to enable Virtual Reality Support and add Windows Mixed Reality which automatically adds PerceptionDevice.dll, HolographicAppRemoting.dll and UnityRemotingWMR.dll to UnityData.vcxitems when building the VS solution from Unity

Disabling Virtual Reality support removed those entries from UnityData.vcxitems and things seem to work for me now!

Answer (score -1):

Try looking for the plugin in x64 folder and if it's available then copy the files from x64 to x86

Comment: This is not a great answer, probably better as a comment and if it solves the original problem, refine this and make it clear to future users why your answer is worth reading.